# Zend Framework Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I'm beginning with Zend Framework and I would like to understand Bootstrap file. I've learned all `_init` methods are executed by default but it seems confusing to me. Anyway that is not what I would like to ask.

A came around the `$this->bootstrap('layout');` action and I'm not sure if I understand this. Is this the resource.layout variable in application.ini file? I would like to really understand the bootstrap process in deep.

**I'm asking you for step by step explanation.**
Thanks in advance!

So this is my bootstrap file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
        ));
        return $moduleLoader;
    }

    function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');

        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        $view->headTitle('Zend Framework Tutorial');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just linked to this question on my twitter stream https://twitter.com/joedevon/status/2464729062, hopefully someone will pop by shortly w/ a good detailed explanation. I got it totally working, but don't totally understand everything it's doing :)

Comment: $this->bootstrap('layout');

This line is ensuring that the 'layout' has been set-up before the rest of _initViewHelpers() has run.

Answer (score 6):

The line from `application.ini`

```
resources.layout[] =
```

is equivalent to:

```
_initLayout() {}
```

in `Bootstrap.php`

Both of them are initializing new object, and this object is set as a `bootstrap` param, which is a container for some application resources (values returned by `_init` methods).

There are executed one by one, so to ensure one resource is initialized before the the current one, you force the order, using:

```
_initSomeResource() {
    $this->bootstrap('otherResource');
    // ..
    return $someValue; 
}

_initOtherResource() {
    // .. 
}
```

So the order of instantiating of the resources is:

1. `otherResource`
2. `someResource`

Now, you may also use:

```
$bootstrap->getParam('someResource'); // returns $someValue
```

Note, that you may encounter `Circular Dependency` error, when you try to execute each other before each one.

You may use as many `_init` methods you need, but to make them reusable, you may separate them to their own class, implementing `Zend_Application_Resource_Abstract` class.

There are some *out of the box* application resources, which you may find in `Zend/Application/Resource` directory. These are the resources, you are refering from `application.ini`, i.e.:

```
resources.view.encoding = "utf-8" ; in application.ini
Zend/Application/Resource/View.php (path to the resource class)
Zend_Application_Resource_View::setEncoding('UTF-8'); // equivalent pseudocode
```

Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

refer to this [documentation](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) for available options.

Zend_Application will automatically bootstrap anything in the application.ini which begins with resources.

Note that if you do not put something in your ini file, it will not be loaded. E.g. by default no layout is loaded. If you include either one, or both, of the following the layout will be enabled for the application:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = default
```

Most important to realise is that it will load the defaults where you have omitted values, let me explain: By default the bootstrap won't have a view resource available, because none is set in the ini. But if you put this in the ini:

```
resources.view[] =
```

then you can call:

```
$this->boostrap('view');
$view = $this->boostrap()->getResource('view');
```

Then you can do something with your app's view from the bootstrap, e.g.

```
$view->doctype("HTML5");
```

Also, your _initAutoload is not necessary anymore, and can be replaced with

```
appnamespace = ""
```

in the .ini. I concur that the bootstrapping and ini options are very poorly documented.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

else for hands-on learning:

```
protected function _initIniDump()
{
    $ini = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'development');
    Zend_Debug::dump($ini->toArray(), 'APPLICATION.INI');die();
}
```

In that dump you will see that Zend will iterate over the resources array, anything that it recognizes, it loads to best of it's knowledge

:)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that: calling $this->boostrap('resource'); will not work if 'resource' is not in the application/configs/application.ini file. So my answer to your question would be 'yes', you have to define the layout resource in the application.ini file with the following : resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts" (or another dir.)

Unfortunately the zend Framework documentation is really bad in my opinion. Especially on this topic.

My opinion is that you should wait for a version with a better documentation if you want to get deep into the details and workings of the Zend Framework (or you can check the source code of the Zend Library Classes if you have the time).

Comment: Yes, in this case is the ZF manual just loads of crap and no examples. Really bad. I hope that there will be some tutorials soon / or better manual.

Comment: The ZF manual is a bit lame at times and sort of like a wiki/tutorial. However, if you keep reading and keep programming stuff with ZF, eventually you understand all the parts you work with - at least that is how it was for me. The docs cover most things, but they are scattered here and there. So it does take lots of exposure and fiddling to get a deeper understanding of what is happening. Good luck!