# Zend Framework Bootstrap functions from where to get

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I find many functions used in Bootstrap class in Zend Framework applications
like:

```
_initRoute()
_initLocale()
_initLayout()
.......
```

but i searched for it's reference but I fond nothing

```
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
```

none of them contains any of these functions.

Where can i find the full reference of that functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, these are [resource plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) located in `library/Zend/Application/Resource/`. You may create also your custom ones.

See [My detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074139/zend-framework-layout/4927041#4927041) to [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074139/zend-framework-layout/4927041) which should fit also to this one.

Also, see `BootstrapAbstract.php`:

```
/**
 * Get class resources (as resource/method pairs)
 *
 * Uses get_class_methods() by default, reflection on prior to 5.2.6,
 * as a bug prevents the usage of get_class_methods() there.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getClassResources()
{
    if (null === $this->_classResources) {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.6') === -1) {
            $class        = new ReflectionObject($this);
            $classMethods = $class->getMethods();
            $methodNames  = array();

            foreach ($classMethods as $method) {
                $methodNames[] = $method->getName();
            }
        } else {
            $methodNames = get_class_methods($this);
        }

        $this->_classResources = array();
        foreach ($methodNames as $method) {
            if (5 < strlen($method) && '_init' === substr($method, 0, 5)) {
                $this->_classResources[strtolower(substr($method, 5))] = $method;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_classResources;
}
```

Comment: Indeed the correct answer explained well in the other question!

Comment: firstly thank you. well but where can i find all standard resources? for example i need to customize the database adapter, i need to customize layouts .. do i have to search Google every time i need such information? or there are standard methods or resources to be used??

Comment: @Ahmed I have updated the answer: The resources are located in library/Zend/Application/Resource/

Answer (score 3):

These function aren't defined anywhere, just in `Bootstrap.php` - these are called resource methods. At the bootstraping process, ZF automatically calls each function defined in `Bootstrap.php` which starts with `_init`.

Read more here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html